# Tomcat7 cluster failing to start on FreeBSD 10.3

Tags: tomcat7, freebsd

I have 2 FreeBSD 10.3 Servers running Tomcat7.  I wanted to enable the Clustering option, `<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>` and when I restart the service I get:

> org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl start 
>   SEVERE: Unable to join multicast group, make sure your system has multicasting
>   enabled.

I have ip_mroute_load="yes" added to my /boot/loader.conf to enable multicast.  And doing a kldstat confirms it is loaded.

> 3    1 0xffffffff819cf000 171b8    ip_mroute.ko

When I remove the `<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>` line from my server.xml files... everything starts up just fine.

Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: what is network between boxes?

Comment: Just a Gigabit Cisco Catalyst 2960 Switch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to enable a multicast routing daemon in userland. Try building and installing ports/net/mrouted or **pkg install mrouted**. Then configure /usr/local/etc/mrouted.conf

For more information, consult the [FreeBSD handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-routing.html).